# CursorIndexOutOfBoundException index 0 size 0 in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursor

I'm trying to implement a feature in my app where a **`SOS`** button will be displayed in the login screen if the user has logged in before. If not, the **`SOS`** button will not be displayed.

For this, I have created a database table in SQLite solely for tracking whether the user has logged in before or not.
Whenever the user logs in, a string value `LoggedIn` will be inserted in the table.

While loading the login page, the data for login status is fetched from the database table. If the data is `LoggedIn`, I'm displaying the **`SOS`** button, otherwise, I'm making the **`SOS`** button invisible.

I am using the following method to get the status data, but I'm getting an exception:

> CursorIndexOutOfBoundException index 0 size 0

```
 public String getLoggedInStatus()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String status="";
        String query = "SELECT * FROM  LoggedInStatus";   //LoggedInStatus is my table to store login status

        Cursor  cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

        if (cursor != null) {
          cursor.moveToFirst();
          status = cursor.getString(0); 
          //Exception is occuring in the above line
        }

        return status;
    }
```

How do I fix this? How do I read data from the cursor correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is saying that you are trying to read (extract data) from the first column of the first row BUT that there is no first row and thus that index 0 (row 1) is out of bounds (column 0 would always exist as otherwise the query would be invalid and fail with another message (probably a syntax error)).

The reason being that no rows have been returned. Checking for a null Cursor from the `rawQuery` method (or the equivalent `query` convenience method) is useless as a Cursor will be returned. However, if the Cursor has no rows it will be empty and thus the `getCount` method would return 0 .

The Cursor's `move????` methods (such as `moveToFirst`) will also return false if the move cannot be made.

As such you could, instead of using `if (cursor != null) {........}`, use `if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { ...... }` or if `(cursor.getCount() > 0) {......}`.

As such the following would fix the issue :-

```
public String getLoggedInStatus()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String status="";
    String query = "SELECT * FROM  LoggedInStatus";   //LoggedInStatus is my table to store login status

    Cursor  cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst) { //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        status = cursor.getString(0); 
    }
    cursor.close() //<<<<<<<<<< You should always close cursors when done with them
    return status;
}
```

- Note in the case that there are no rows to be returned `getLoggedInStatus` method will return an empty string.

Comment: All answers were useful but yours was great for being descriptive. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

check count also greater than zero

```
if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0)
{
cursor.moveToFirst();
status = cursor.getString(0); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is **almost** correct. However `cursor.moveToFirst();` returns `true` or `false` depending if the `Cursor` was able to iterate.

So, as a default android's `Cursor` has index `-1` as default to make it work inside `while` loops. To make sure that there are any elements inside your `Cursor` wrap your code inside this `if` statement:

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()) {
   cursor.getString(0); 
   // To get the element count you can use cursor.getCount();
}
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#moveToNext()

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there are no rows in the table.  
To check it there are various ways, one of them is this:

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
{
    status = cursor.getString(0); 
}
```